# Two planets - "exchange orbit" scenario - Does it cause climate shift?

Tags: climate, orbital-mechanics

I have an earth-like planet with a roughly earth-like orbital period, that is in a stable co-orbital scenario with another largish body. Similar to Janus and Epimetheus but planets rather than moons.

At every approach/exchange the planet experiences geologic upheaval and climatic shift. Geologic due to tidal forces from the close approach, causing severe earthquakes. Climatic because of the exchange of orbital position.

This is for a young adult scifi. The scenario will only be described indirectly and will not have to stand up to hard scifi level scrutiny, but I would like to keep it realistic and plausible.

How much climate shift would be possible?

Comment: Hi Felix, welcome.. One: I think you mean "disturb" orbits, not "exchange" orbits. That is what happens with Janus and Epimetheus https://www.planetary.org/articles/janus-epimetheus-swap ..and two: this is not science-based, but I would suggest to add some more detail about the big one, which is in Earth's path.. How heavy is the big one ?  When the big one would be big enough to *sling* the smaller Earth into a more elliptical orbit, you'll get extreme seasons!

Comment: I just found this: https://planetplanet.net/2018/07/02/horseshoe-planetary-system/ Apparently the correct term is "horseshoe orbit"

Comment: Please don't re-ask a closed question, please edit the closed question instead.

Comment: I did edit it. It originally got closed because I had a list of 4 closely related questions for the same scenario. I was advised to ask one question per post so I opened two more. Obviously being the same scenario the bulk of the posts is duplicated. Seems like one can't win in this forum...